# Android bulkTransfer return -1 when read data but there is really some data in the buffer

Tags: android, usb, host

I write a app in galaxy tab p7300 to communicate with a key (scsi device) via otg cable. I can  read data first time with bulkTransfer(),but can not the next time . Then I use Ellisys Visual USB to sniff data and I find that the key really return 13 bytes data. But in the android client (GT-P7300) I receive -1 that bulkTransfer return. I have run out my idea. Thanks for anybody that can give me  a piece of clues.

Comment: A return of a negative number usually corresponds to an error code for a function like this. Check whatever class you are using for any `ERROR_` variables.

Comment: Thanks ,Matt Clark.  Make me confused is that the key actually return the ture data, but bulkTransfer return -1.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure out your problem. Happy Coding! And merry Christmas! :p

Comment: Ha ha,acturally I`m a Chinese ,so we do not celebrate Christmas .So I should say wish you a merry Christmas.

Comment: Well crap... Thanks! hahahaha

Answer (score 7):

When using the USB Bulk transfer, here is a list of things to check when transaction fails

a) Verify the **direction of the endpoint** you have passed the bulkTransfer function

b) ensure that the buffer has sufficient **length to store** incoming data

c) The **length field** is perhaps the most important. If you know the exact size of the response, use it.

d) The **Timeout parameter**. If you send a query to the device and do not provide enough timeout when listening to the response, the bulkTransfer can return -1.

It looks like the timeout is affecting behavior in your Case. My suggestion is to use the exact number of bytes in the length fields for each response, and use a longer timeout (like 1000) so you give enough time for the bulk request to complete.

Comment: Thanks Jan, what you said I have tried, my problem is the bulkIn endpoint return a stall signal ,so I send a command to clear the stall.After that,I can receive the data normally ,but when the stall signal occurred again ,I send the command to clear it, while it did not work well when I receive data.It return -1 but there is some data actually.I have run out of my ideas.

Comment: @Wayne.liu are you able to solve this problem? if yes please share your findings!

Comment: @Wayne.liu Please share the solution to the problem you were facing. Thanks

Comment: I sorry to answer so late ,but I have not found the solution yet.@MohsinNaeem @Sagar

Comment: How do you clear the stall? What command to send and how? Cannot find any documentation on that in Android :(

Answer (score 2):

Its too late to post a solution , but in case in future someone needs help about it can get an answer from here.

I faced the same issue. I was using Android (Samsung galaxy s3) as usb host device. I figured out about the read endpoint and write endpoint not trasferring data using USB BulkTransfer. I tried to switch the endpoints for host mode case, it recognized and successfully write/read the data.

```
 mReadEndpoint = mDataInterface.getEndpoint(0);// tweaking endpoints // 1 was for read and 0 was for write
 mWriteEndpoint = mDataInterface.getEndpoint(1);
```

P.S there is an application available for android named "USB device info". It helped me a lot in understanding interfaces and endpoints of my usb device.