# Android Usb Host Receive Data

Tags: android, usb, host

I try to reading data from my evalboard. It  is Stellaris EKK-LM4F232 Evalutaion Kit. It has  five buttons. I push a button on board and send data to my android device. For example, i  push one times, and board send to 1, and second times send to 2....  I receive the first value (it mean 1) from android device when i  push the button first time. But when i push the button again, i can't receive any other values like 2 ,3 ,4 ,... . 
Here is my code for reading. It  read continuously when it is start. Can you help me?

```
public void startDataRecieve() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            UsbEndpoint endpoint = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < intf.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
                if (intf.getEndpoint(i).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN) {
                    endpoint = intf.getEndpoint(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest(); // create an URB
            boolean initilzed = request.initialize(connection, endpoint);

            if (!initilzed) {
                Log.e("USB CONNECTION FAILED", "Request initialization failed for reading");
                return;
            }
            while (true) {
                int bufferMaxLength = endpoint.getMaxPacketSize();
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferMaxLength);


                if (request.queue(buffer, bufferMaxLength) == true) {
                    if (connection.requestWait() == request) {
                        String result = new String(buffer.array());
                            Log.i("GELEN DATA : ", result);
                            listener.readData(result);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }).start();
}
```

If you can't understand very well the same question is here asked by one
[Android bulkTransfer return -1 when read data but there is really some data in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016943/android-bulktransfer-return-1-when-read-data-but-there-is-really-some-data-in-t)

After the discusstion with @Mike Ortiz I put  all my code in here. When I click the buttonSend  android device send "START" command to device then reading start. 
When i send to android device to first value i can get it but after first value i don't get any value from usb device. I am sure the usb device sends the values.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {

private static final String TAG = "MAIN ACTIVITY TEST ";

private Button buttonConnect;
private Button butonSend;
private Button buttonDisconnect;
private TextView textViewResult;
private UsbDevice device;

private Thread readThread;
private UsbManager usbManager;
private UsbDeviceConnection connection;
private UsbInterface usbInterface;
private UsbEndpoint usbEndpointIn;
private UsbEndpoint usbEndpointOut;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initView();

    PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter);

    usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = usbManager.getDeviceList();
    Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();

    while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
        UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();

        if (device.getVendorId() == 7358 && device.getProductId() == 3) {
            this.device = device;
            usbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
            break;
        }
    }

    butonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            usbInterface = device.getInterface(0);
            connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
            connection.claimInterface(usbInterface, false);

            for (int i = 0; i < usbInterface.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
                UsbEndpoint end = usbInterface.getEndpoint(i);
                if (end.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN) {
                    usbEndpointIn = end;

                } else {
                    usbEndpointOut = end;
                }
            }

            //SEND START COMMAND TO  THE USB DEVICE; 
            int result = connection.bulkTransfer(usbEndpointOut, "START".getBytes(), "START".getBytes().length, 1000);
            Log.e("SEND RESULT", result + "");


            //START READING in run method
            readThread = new Thread(MainActivity.this);
            readThread.start();




        }
    });

    buttonDisconnect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mRunning = false;
            //readThread.stop();
            connection.releaseInterface(usbInterface);
            connection.close();
            Log.e(TAG, "Connection CLosed.");

        }
    });
}

private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
private final BroadcastReceiver usbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if (device != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cihaza izin verildi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cihaza izin verilmedi.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for device " + device);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

private boolean mRunning;

private void initView() {
    butonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
    buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConnect);
    textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
    buttonDisconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDisconnect);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    mRunning = true; 

    //READ VALUE UNTIL DISCONNECT
    while (mRunning) {

        byte[] bytes = new byte[usbEndpointIn.getMaxPacketSize()];
        int result = connection.bulkTransfer(usbEndpointIn, bytes, bytes.length, 1000);
        if(result > 0)
        Log.e("RESULT : " + result, "  VALUE : " + new String(bytes));


    }
    Log.d("Thread", "STOPPPED");

}
```

}

Comment: I think the problem here might have been that you were reading the data too soon (forcing the listener to get the data that may not have been sent yet, reading an empty buffer (hence the -1)). I don't see where your listener is defined, but by default, the listener may be running on the main thread, not the thread you're communicating to serial device on.

Comment: I want to get printer status (paper near to end OR end).I am using 0x1D, 0x52, 0x31 command from android. I tried with both OUT and IN. But not getting proper response from the printer. If i use OUT then printer returns me 5 and for IN printer returns me 8. Is there anything helpful for me or guide me how can i get printer status? any example code?

Answer (score 5):

Which condition fails in your loop? `(request.queue(buffer, bufferMaxLength) == true)` or `(connection.requestWait() == request)`? If it's the second, I might suggest using `.equals()` instead of the reference comparison `==`.

Have you tried to use bulk transfer instead of requests?

```
private UsbManager mManager; 
private UsbDevice  mDevice;
private UsbDeviceConnection mDeviceConnection;
private UsbInterface mInterface;
private UsbEndpoint mEndpointIn;   

public void run() {
    while (mEndpointIn != null && mDeviceConnection != null) {
        byte[] recordIn = new byte[mEndpointIn.getMaxPacketSize()];
        int receivedLength = mDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(mEndpointIn, recordIn,
                                                       recordIn.length, mTimeout);
        if (receivedLength > -1) passDataToListener(recordIn);
    }
}

public void initializeCommunication(Context context) throws UsbDeviceException {

    mInterface = findHidInterface();

    if (mManager != null && mDevice != null && mInterface != null) {
        mDeviceConnection = mManager.openDevice(mDevice);

        if (mDeviceConnection != null) {
            if (mDeviceConnection.claimInterface(mInterface, true)) {
                UsbEndpoint usbEndpointOut = null;
                UsbEndpoint usbEndpointIn = null;

                //
                // Look for Interrupt endpoints
                //
                for (int i = 0; i < mInterface.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
                    UsbEndpoint usbEndpoint = mInterface.getEndpoint(i);

                    if (usbEndpoint.getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_INT) {
                        if (usbEndpoint.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT) {
                            usbEndpointOut = usbEndpoint;

                        } else {
                            usbEndpointIn = usbEndpoint;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (usbEndpointOut == null || usbEndpointIn == null) {
                    Log.w(DEBUG, "No USB endpoints found.");
                }

                mEndpointOut = usbEndpointOut;
                mEndpointIn = usbEndpointIn;

            } else {
                mDeviceConnection.close();
                Log.w(DEBUG, "USB claim interface failed.");
            }
        } else {
            Log.w(DEBUG, "USB open device failed.");
        }
    } else {
        Log.w(DEBUG, "Some essential USB variables were null.");
    }
}

/**
 * Find the HID interface.
 * 
 * @return
 *      Return the HID interface if found, otherwise null.
 */
private UsbInterface findHidInterface() {
    if (mDevice != null) {
        final int interfaceCount = mDevice.getInterfaceCount();

        for (int interfaceIndex = 0; interfaceIndex < interfaceCount; interfaceIndex++) {
            UsbInterface usbInterface = mDevice.getInterface(interfaceIndex);

            //
            // Can add UsbInterface.getInterfaceSubclass() and 
            // UsbInterface.getInterfaceProtocol() for more specifics.
            //

            if (usbInterface.getInterfaceClass() == UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_HID) {
                return usbInterface;
            }
        }

        Log.w(DEBUG, "HID interface not found.");
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: the problem  is (connection.requestWait() == request). But I can get first value. For example i send 1 first time from usb device. I can get it but second time i send 2 , i don't take the value in android device. If this condition is not correct, why does it work in when i get first value?

Comment: I tried your solution with bulktransfer the receivedLenght always return -1 after i get first value.

Comment: Interesting, I use similar code to what I've posted in a project of my own and it works for multiple messages. My next suggestion would be to use a USB Analyzer to confirm the kit is actually sending data to the phone after the first button press.

Comment: I added a link in my question, you can see same problem with me. Maybe you can find another solution. Thanks for everything

Comment: Can you post the rest of your relevant code? Do you call `mDeviceCommunication.claimInterface(intf, true);` , etc? Are you communicating over the correct type of interface? I believe you want to be looking for a HID interface, specifically, and only endpoints from that specific interface. You can download the app "USB Device Info" to enumerate the endpoints and interfaces for your usb device.

Comment: In usb device has one usbInterface and two endpoints. They are bulkEndpoint and one of them in, the other is out. I updated my question and add  all  my code.

Comment: can you tell me , what is your usb device and what is your android device? And I want to learn your devices endpoint types? Please

Comment: @Zapateus The interface is HID and the end point type is bulk. I added some code around initializing communication, which I use in my own project. I think my code might be more robust around grabbing the correct interface and at the very least, has a good amount of error logging to let you know know where things are going wrong. Hope it works for you.

Comment: in your solution there is  if (usbEndpoint.getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_INT) clause but my endpoint types are USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK. Do you know what is difference. And my interface type is not HID vendor specific type. But i think ,the problem is my endpoint types? isn't is?