# read from HID devices in Android

Tags: android, usb, hid

Hi I am new to USB Android. First of all sorry if I don't explain the things clearly. I am currently working on a project which uses USB. I want to receive the values from the USB where Another module will send the values through USB. I have referred some links but I am not be able to find my need. The USB connected device will be like HID device. I don't have any picture about USB. Please guide me .

Answer (score 0):

[Check out a previous answer of mine,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273453/android-usb-host-receive-data/19433823#19433823) which goes through the process of initializing a usb connection with an HID device.

Comment: how to list USB HID devices in Android?

Comment: @Sathish In the link I provided, findHIDInterface() iterates through all USB interfaces and returns the first HID interface. You can modify that function to print out data about each HID interface rather than return the first HID interface encountered.

Comment: if (usbEndpoint.getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_INT) {
                        if (usbEndpoint.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT) {
                            usbEndpointOut = usbEndpoint;

                        } else {
                            usbEndpointIn = usbEndpoint;
                        }
 In this code You are assigning to usbEndpointIn. How to display those endpoints?

Comment: USBEndpoint has getter functions for address, attributes, direction, etc. You can print these attributes to logcat.

Comment: I have posted with the image my problem. Can you help me in it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012287/usb-hid-read-and-write-in-android-bugs