# Android program crashes when writing to TextView in loop

Tags: android, multithreading, usb, textview

I am trying to write a serial monitor.  I followed the Android guide for USB input and used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273453/android-usb-host-receive-data) as a reference.  I got the code in the post working, but I don't want to write to the log.  I want to write the input to a textView (or some text field on the UI), but instead it just crashes.  I would also like to be able to read from an editable text field and send the data through the USB connection.

My setup is very similar to that in the post above, but with a different run() function:

```
@Override
public void run() 
{
    mRunning = true;

    terminalWindow.append("Hello from thread.");
    while(mRunning)
    {
        byte[] recordIn = new byte[endpoint.getMaxPacketSize()];
        if(connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, recordIn,recordIn.length, 1000)>0)
        {
            String infoIn = new String(recordIn);
            terminalWindow.append(infoIn.toString());
        }


    }
}
```

How can I get the infoIn string to write to the TextView terminalWindow?  Do I need to add some sort of sleep() function?  (I tried counting to 10million between reads, but as soon as it returns, it crashes as well)

-----------UPDATE

Thank you for the quick responses.  I had to change the code somewhat.  In order to connect to the serial bridge, I have to disconnect my Android device from my computer, which means I don't have any logs.  However, I think the problem I'm having is the same without the calls to the USB library:

```
05-19 22:50:38.674: W/dalvikvm(7809):       threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4159c7c0)
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1617
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:869)
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4253)
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10546)
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10501)
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809):     at android.widget.TextView.updateAfterEdit(TextView.java:7340)
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809):     at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7363)
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9076)
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.append(SpannableStringBuilder.java:253)
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.append(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809):     at android.widget.TextView.append(TextView.java:3355)
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809):     at android.widget.TextView.append(TextView.java:3342)
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809):     at com.knolledge.cerealmonitor.MainActivity.run(MainActivity.java:119)
05-19 22:50:38.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7809):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Looking at this log and with the context that CommonsWare gave, the problem does seem to be that I have the thread updating the UI.  I don't even want to use a new thread, honestly.  However, the Android documentation suggests it.  What is the best way of doing this then?  Should I have the thread send an event and have the UI listen for a newly read buffer?  And does the connection.bulkTransfer just poll the connection forever, or is there a way to have it sleep and only read incoming packets after an interrupt?

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash. Most likely, it is because the above code is running on a background thread, and you cannot update the UI from a background thread.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, @CommonsWare.  I posted the logs.

Comment: "Should I have the thread send an event and have the UI listen for a newly read buffer?" -- have the background thread read from the buffer and provide the newly-retrieved bytes to the UI layer for processing. You can do that using `runOnUiThread()` as Pardych suggests, or a `Handler`, or an event bus (e.g., greenrobot's EventBus). "And does the connection.bulkTransfer just poll the connection forever, or is there a way to have it sleep and only read incoming packets after an interrupt?" -- I have not used the USB APIs, so I cannot answer that, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `runOnUiThread` for `terminalWindow` appends or use `AsyncTask` instead of `Thread` with `onProgressUpdate/publishProgress` for text appending
second way is more correct