# android, libaums: java.io.IOException: Could not write to device

Tags: android, sockets

I'm using the [libaums](https://github.com/magnusja/libaums) library to write some files to a usb device:

```
private class CopyToUsbTask extends AsyncTask<CopyToUsbTaskParam, Integer, Void> {


    List<CopyToUsbTaskParam.SingleToUsbParam> paramList;
    private CopyToUsbTaskParam.SingleToUsbParam param;

    public CopyToUsbTask() {
        Log.e(TAG, "CopyToUsbTask: Constructor");       
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(CopyToUsbTaskParam... params) {
        paramList = params[0].paramList;
        while(!paramList.isEmpty() ){
            param = paramList.remove(0);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        queryUriMetaData(param.from);

        try {
            UsbFile root = currentFs.getRootDirectory();
            UsbFile dirTo = null;
            for(UsbFile usbFile : root.listFiles()){
                if(usbFile.getName().endsWith(param.toDir)){
                    dirTo = usbFile;
                }
            }

            UsbFile file = dirTo.createFile(param.name);  

            InputStream inputStream = activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(param.from);
            OutputStream outputStream = UsbFileStreamFactory.createBufferedOutputStream(file, currentFs);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1337];
            int count;
            long total = 0;

            while ((count = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1){
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, count);                 
            }

            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            file.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error copying!", e);
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "copy time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));

    }return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        int mid = Integer.valueOf(param.name.split("_")[0]);
        Log.e(TAG, "onPostExecute, mid= " + mid);
        Helper.deleteBookOrder(mid);        
    }
}
```

Sometimes (especially, when paramList.size() > 1) I get error messages like:

> java.io.IOException: Could not write to device, result == -1 errno 88 Socket operation on non-socket

Can't find what this error message is supposed to mean.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I experience a similar error using this library. Instead of using a static buffer size of 1337, there is a method in FileSystem.java called getChunkSize(). You can set the buffer size using that method. That seemed to resolve the issue for me.

I also emailed the developer of this library regarding this issue and this was his response:

"so this is a weird error everyone has sometimes. Usually unplugging and plugging in again works.
I did some research and found out that -1 only means that there is some kind of error. But the actual error is in the errno variable of the Linux kernel. I don’t have any idea how to get this value from Android/Java.

I also found this: [Android bulkTransfer return -1 when read data but there is really some data in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016943/android-bulktransfer-return-1-when-read-data-but-there-is-really-some-data-in-t)
He explains that he found out that the endpoint was stalled, this could also be the case. Unfortunately I don’t really know how to reset this stall status and he also doesn’t really explain it."

Hope this helps!

Comment: The error doesn't seem to reappear, after I set file.setLength value, as described in the link above.

Comment: It reappeared. Less often tho.

Comment: Could you provide some of code that solved the issue because i am getting same issue and not be able to find workaround. Could you show me use of  *getChunkSize()* ?

Comment: You should be able to see this in the [sample code](https://github.com/magnusja/libaums/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/github/mjdev/libaums/usbfileman/MainActivity.java) in libaums.

Comment: byte[] bytes = new byte[currentFs.getChunkSize()];

Answer (score 0):

Similar error calling inputStream.read(bytes)
Error: "java.io.IOException: Could not write to device, result == -1 errno 2 No such file or directory".

Resolved using FileInputStream class for the InputStream.